# How to keep a Postgresql database connection open with Python

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am running a loop, and in each iteration I go to the PostGres database to find certain matching records. My issue is that it takes too long to open a new database connection at each time through the loop.

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(mycredentials)
db_connect = engine.connect()

query = ("""SELECT ("CustomerId") AS "CustomerId", 
                ("LastName") AS "LastName", 
                ("FirstName") AS "FirstName",
                ("City") AS "City", 
                FROM 
                    public."postgres_table" 
                WHERE (LEFT("LastName", 4) = %(blocking_lastname)s 
                    AND LEFT("City", 4) = %(blocking_city)s) 
                    OR (LEFT("FirstName", 3) = %(blocking_firstname)s
                    AND LEFT("City", 4) = %(blocking_city)s)
""")

for index, row in df_loop.iterrows():
    blocking_lastname = row['LastName'][:4]  
    blocking_firstname = row['FirstName'][:3]  
    blocking_city = row['City'][:4]  

    df = pd.read_sql(query, db_connect, params= {
                                        'blocking_firstname': blocking_firstname,
                                        'blocking_lastname': blocking_lastname, 
                                        'blocking_city': blocking_city})
```

This code works, but it doesn't appear to be keeping the database connection open since there is too much latency with the query. (Note: The table columns have indexes.)

UPDATE: I updated the code above, using db_connect as an object outside of the loop rather than engine.connect() as a call in pd.read_sql() as I originally had it written.

Comment: The code you have there is correct.  Is your question answered?

Comment: No the question still stands; here I only added the loop for clarity. I am still trying to figure out if the session is staying open or if it is opening every time I call db_connect.

Comment: You're not "calling" `db_connect`.  You're just passing an existing object.  It will not be reopened.  However, that can't be your actual code, because you have 4 substitution parameters and you're only supplying 3 values.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. That makes sense re: passing an existing object. Thank you for confirming that it is not opening a new connection every time pd.read_sql() is called. Regarding the parameters, "blocking_city" is used twice in the SQL statement, so only 3 values are needed to be passed in.

Comment: The query shown in your sample text is using `%s`.  The entries aren't named, so it's going to expect exactly 4 substitutions.  Is that not your real code?

Comment: Tim,  "blocking_city" is used twice in the SQL statement, so only 3 values are needed to be passed in. I updated the code to reflect this. (this is not my real code; it's just a simple excerpt intended to convey the db_connect question).

Comment: Yep, now it's correct.  Do you really need all of these as pandas dataframes?  pandas is handy, but it's quite heavy.  It might be interesting to try these queries without pandas and see what the time is.  Of course, that might not be trivial to do.

Comment: What would be the alternative? Most of my code leverages Pandas. I'd be interested in exploring other solutions; I've just always used Pandas.

Comment: If you're already heavily invested, then that's fine.  I'm showing my personal bias here, but I see a lot of people using pandas for tasks that would be much easier solved with numpy or even a list of rows.  Pandas does a good job of presentation, but enumerating rows or columns is quite painful.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, Tim. I will explore these options moving forward.